# Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context - Error when convert Java to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have well managed code and project in `Java`. But I need to develop another project from it in `Kotlin`. So, I converted all code as possible in `Kotlin`. But there is code of `ZipFileManager.kt` which is use to zip/unzip files.

Here is code(`Kotlin`):

```
object ZipFileManager {

    private val BUFFER_SIZE = 6 * 1024

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun zip(files: Array<String>, zipFile: String) {
        var origin: BufferedInputStream? = null
        val out = ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(zipFile)))
        try {
            val data = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)

            for (file in files) {
                val fi = FileInputStream(file)
                origin = BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE)
                try {
                    val entry = ZipEntry(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                    out.putNextEntry(entry)
                    var count: Int
                    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)     {
                        out.write(data, 0, count)
                    }
                } finally {
                    origin.close()
                }
            }
        } finally {
            out.close()
        }
    }

    fun unzip(zipFileUrl: String, fileLocation: String) {
        try {
            val f = File(fileLocation)
            if (!f.isDirectory) {
                f.mkdirs()
            }
            ZipInputStream(FileInputStream(zipFileUrl)).use { zin ->
                var ze: ZipEntry? = null
                while ((ze = zin.nextEntry) != null) {
                    //                    Log.e("UnZipFILE", "Unzipping....");
                    val path = fileLocation + ze!!.name

                    if (ze.isDirectory) {
                        val unzipFile = File(path)
                        if (!unzipFile.isDirectory) {
                            unzipFile.mkdirs()
                        }
                    } else {
                        FileOutputStream(path, false).use { fout ->
                            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                            var read: Int
                            while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                fout.write(buffer, 0, read)
                            }
                            zin.closeEntry()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("UnZipException", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
        }

    }
}
```

So, I am trying through this code but It's shows compile time error like:

`Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context` in the `fun zip` at the line `while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)`

and give another same compile time error at line `while ((ze = zin.nextEntry) != null)` and at the line `while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) != -1)`.

So, my big problem is to use this code in `Kotlin`. So, any body can help who have knowledge of `Kotlin` and how can I use this type of looping structure in `Kotlin`?

There is also I have `Java` code if any body want to see:

```
public class ZipFileManager {

    private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 6 * 1024;

    public static void zip(String[] files, String zipFile) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile)));
        try {
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            for (String file : files) {
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE);
                try {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                    out.putNextEntry(entry);
                    int count;
                    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                        out.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                } finally {
                    origin.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public static void unzip(String zipFileUrl, String fileLocation) {
        try {
            File f = new File(fileLocation);
            if (!f.isDirectory()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }
            try (ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFileUrl))) {
                ZipEntry ze = null;
                while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
//                    Log.e("UnZipFILE", "Unzipping....");
                    String path = fileLocation + ze.getName();

                    if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                        File unzipFile = new File(path);
                        if (!unzipFile.isDirectory()) {
                            unzipFile.mkdirs();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path, false)) {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int read;
                            while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                fout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            }
                            zin.closeEntry();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("UnZipException", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
}
```

I also try to manage loop like:

```
do {
    ze = zin.nextEntry
} while (ze != null)
```

But than file is not got unzip properly or its broken. So, if any body have idea of managing this type of loop than it will very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am converting your `Java` code to `Kotlin`

I have facing this issue earlier
`Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context`

Use this code here is your solution

```
object ZipFileManager {

private val BUFFER_SIZE = 6 * 1024
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun zip(files: Array<String>, zipFile: String) {
    var origin: BufferedInputStream? = null
    val out = ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(zipFile)))
    try {
        val data = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)

        for (file in files) {
            val fi = FileInputStream(file)
            origin = BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE)
            try {
                val entry = ZipEntry(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                out.putNextEntry(entry)
                var count: Int= origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                while (count != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count)
                    count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)
                }
            } finally {
                origin.close()
            }
        }
    } finally {
        out.close()
    }
}

fun unzip(zipFileUrl: String, fileLocation: String) {
    try {
        val f = File(fileLocation)
        if (!f.isDirectory) {
            f.mkdirs()
        }
        ZipInputStream(FileInputStream(zipFileUrl)).use { zin ->
            var ze: ZipEntry? = null
            ze = zin.nextEntry
            while (ze != null) {
                //                    Log.e("UnZipFILE", "Unzipping....");
                val path = fileLocation + ze!!.name

                if (ze.isDirectory) {
                    val unzipFile = File(path)
                    if (!unzipFile.isDirectory) {
                        unzipFile.mkdirs()
                    }
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream(path, false).use { fout ->
                        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                        var read: Int= zin.read(buffer)
                        while (read != -1) {
                            fout.write(buffer, 0, read)
                            read = zin.read(buffer)
                        }
                        zin.closeEntry()
                    }
                }
                ze = zin.nextEntry
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("UnZipException", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I am trying.

Comment: Its My plesure, to helping each other. -:)